# How to browse files on a webserver?

Tags: webserver

I have a web server with IP address and port. 
I would like to browse all files on this web server. How can view and upload new files there?

For example, I have already tried via a web browser:

192.168.101.190:2870

But there is an error: 404 Not Found

192.168.101.190:2870/name1.xml/r/n

403 Forbidden

I have access to the files for example: *.xml

1. 192.168.101.190:2870/name1.xml
2. 192.168.101.190:2870/name2.xml

   Server: NFLC/3.0 UPnP/1.0 DLNADOC/1.50

Comment: Can you elaborate? Which web server are you using, IIS, apache, Nginx?

Comment: Really, I am not sure, it is something from this company https://www.access-company.com

How can I check easily?


I see it in the web browser when I put one file with an XML extension: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0" xmlns:microsoft="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:WMPNSS-1-0" xmlns:df="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2008/09/devicefoundation" xmlns:pnpx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/pnpx/2005/11" xmlns:dlna="urn:schemas-dlna-org:device-1-0">

Answer (score 1):

The feature you're looking for is Directory Listing/Directory Browsing. If your web server is:

- Apache refer to: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings#Directory_Listings
- IIS refer to: https://blogs.iis.net/bills/how-to-enable-directory-browsing-with-iis7-web-config
- Nginx refer to: https://nginxlibrary.com/enable-directory-listing/

Comment: ...and what do you think now??